# How to solve the equation $\ z^2 = i-1 \ $?

Tags: complex-numbers

$\ z^2 = i-1 \ $
Hey guys, I couldn't find a way to solve this problem. The question suggests I replace $\ z\ $ with $\ x+iy\ $ and then go from there, but I always end up having to complete the square and end up with a completely different answer to the back o the book. Can you please help?
Thanks

Comment: $(x + iy)^2 = x^2 - y^2 + i2xy$ so $2xy = 1$ and $x^2 - y^2 = -1$

Comment: @Azlif yes this is called the method of identification and it works.

Comment: I've reached that far but it wants me to solve for z @Azlif

Comment: Why don't you show what result you got and how, so that we can point out the error in your calculation?

Comment: Well, I have $\ x^2 - y^2 = -1 \ $ and $\ x = 1/2y \ $.
I substituted my value for x into the other equation and eventually ended up with $\ 1/4y^2 - y^2 = -1 \ $. Then I got a quartic of $\ 4y^4 +4y^2 - 1 = 0 \ $.
So I completed the square like a quadratic and got $\ 4(a - 0.5)^2 = 1.25 \ $.This gave me a value for a as $\ a = sqrt(5/16) + 0.5 \ $.
Did I complete the square wrong? Thanks

Comment: $\ a = y^2 \ $ as I didn't want to do it as a quartic

Comment: Show your working, your answer, and the answer from the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $$z=x+iy$$ then we get
$$x^2-y^2+2xyi=i-1$$ so we get
$$x^2-y^2+1=0$$
and $$2xy-1=0$$
Can you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

$i-1 = \sqrt2e^{3i\pi/4}$, so $z = \pm \sqrt[4]2e^{3i\pi/8}$.

Comment: Is this solved in polar form of complex numbers?